# Does changing a volatile field update the object?

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

I have the following class

```
public class Guardian {
    volatile String response;
    private Future future;
    private Long time;
}
```

If response was to be modified by thread A, then would thread B see the new value of response via:

```
Guardian guardian = requestManager.getGuardian();
String response = guardian.getResponse();
```

Comment: *"Does changing a volatile field update the object?"* Why wouldn't it? Changing a non-volatile field does.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are aware that string is immutable then yes, the volatile keyword gives you the guaranty that thread B will get the last value of ***response*** no matter on which thread that did happen.

Answer (score 3):

The `volatile` keyword prevents a variable from being cached in thread local memory. What it prevents is `false positives` because your variable has been changed in the main memory but that change hasn't been reflected in local cache memory.

Your example would be subject to a [Race condition](http://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/race-condition) because it would depend on the time taken for each of the threads to execute their relevant operations, but *assuming that isn't a problem*, then yes, you would get the *latest version of that variable in the JVM because it was not cached in thread local memory*.

Answer (score 1):

Does `guardian.getResponse()` just return response? If so, then yes - if thread A modifies `guardian.response` and thread B calls `getResponse()` afterward, then thread B will see the new value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That's precisely the guarantee you get from the volatile keyword.

Answer (score 1):

**YES**

The `volatile` makes the threads to read the actual value each time, while in regular cases threads may cache the value and not be aware of its change